# Cant arrange LinearLayout to show button at the bottom with ListView above

Tags: android, xml, listview

Consider the next piece of xml -

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.android.fiby.fragments.MenuFragment"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_weight="0.7">

        <com.android.fiby.TitleFont
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="#5e240a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:text="בדיקה"
            android:id="@+id/list_title"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:visibility="visible"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom"
              android:gravity="center"
                  android:layout_weight="0.05">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buy_now"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how it looks (ignore the FAB and action button)
[image]

The problem is when i erase element from the list view, the button goes up as well. I want that, no matter how many items are in the ListView, the button will always be at the bottom.

**EDIT**

I've tried using relative layout the following way -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.android.fiby.TitleFont
        android:textColor="#5e240a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="בדיקה"
        android:id="@+id/list_title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>



    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_title"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
        android:id="@+id/buy_now"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

But the problem is that the listview overrides the button -

[image]

**I dont want to chang the height of the list**  since other activities, who disable the image visibility use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RelativeLayout instead LinearLayout and set this button always below your listview. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:visibility="visible"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:id="@+id/listview"
          android:layout_weight="0.05">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buy_now"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listview"
        android:src="@drawable/button"/>
```

Or if you want your button always in the bottom of the activity try this:

```
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Edit1: 
Try setting the ListView above the button instead of the button below the listview.

```
<ListView
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_title"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buy_now"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buy_now"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Or you can use a ScrollView...

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a RelativeLayout and use this line

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

This will dock the item at the bottom